# MATLAB exporting datestr into txt file

Tags: matlab, export, unix-timestamp

So I have this code,

```
%%
%Changing from the unix epoch time to standard DDMMYY format
%Importing the data 
unix_time = [1435763099;1435763109;1435763119;1435763129]; %time of the plot

%Conversion of the epoch data
time = datestr(719529+unix_time/86400,'dd/mmm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
```

And I would like to export the 'time' into a .txt file or excel however I can't find a way to do so without resulting in wrong txt file.

```
fid = fopen('time.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid, time)
fclose(fid);
```

I tried this method but it doesn't seem to give me the correct result i'm looking for which is that I want the results to be the unix_time converted to the dd/mmm/yyyy HH:MM:SS format and export it into a column text file.

I wan't the result to display this in a text file

```
01/Jul/2015 15:04:59,
01/Jul/2015 15:05:09,
01/Jul/2015 15:05:19,
01/Jul/2015 15:05:29,
```

Comment: Do you need the comas in the end of each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case its best to use a different function than `fprintf`.

`dlmwrite` will do the job just fine if used as following:

```
 dlmwrite('time.txt',time,'delimiter','');
```

However, this won't add the comas in the end of each row. If you want the comas, you can just add them to the variable `time` using matrix indexing, before you write it in the file.

```
time(:,end+1):',';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works! great!

However, the end goal of this was to use it as an x axis for the plot and it appears that I get an error. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Is it possible to replace the original data with this newly converted state?

Comment: @SajinGurung That appears to be a completely different question! Consider asking a new one.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the above [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) call is not behaving as desired is because `fprintf` (and, more generally, MATLAB) is column-major, which is why you're getting `00001111....`

This is a good use case for MATLAB's new-ish [`string`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) class, introduced in R2016b. `string` arrays are supported natively by `fprintf` and are printed in the expected fashion:

```
unix_time = [1435763099;1435763109;1435763119;1435763129];
time = string(datestr(719529+unix_time/86400,'dd/mmm/yyyy HH:MM:SS'));

fid = fopen('time.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s,\n', time);
fclose(fid);
```

Which prints out:

```
01/Jul/2015 15:04:59,
01/Jul/2015 15:05:09,
01/Jul/2015 15:05:19,
01/Jul/2015 15:05:29,
```

---

If you're using an older version of MATLAB without support for the `string` class, you can make some minor tweaks in order to get `fprintf` to cooperate. The first inclination when running into the column-major quirk of `fprintf` is to [transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) the data, which should get us where we want, right?

```
unix_time = [1435763099;1435763109;1435763119;1435763129];
time = datestr(719529+unix_time/86400,'dd/mmm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
fprintf('%s,\n', time.')
```

Which gives us:

```
01/Jul/2015 15:04:5901/Jul/2015 15:05:0901/Jul/2015 15:05:1901/Jul/2015 15:05:29,
```

Whoops. It did technically give us what we wanted, but it only ends up being one row. To get around this, we can append a newline character, `\n`, and our comma to the end of each row before transposing:

```
unix_time = [1435763099;1435763109;1435763119;1435763129];
time = datestr(719529+unix_time/86400,'dd/mmm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
fprintf('%s', horzcat(time, repmat(sprintf(',\n'), size(time, 1), 1)).');
```

Which prints:

```
01/Jul/2015 15:04:59,
01/Jul/2015 15:05:09,
01/Jul/2015 15:05:19,
01/Jul/2015 15:05:29,
```

Yay!

Comment: Great! Thanks!
However, the end goal was to use the converted values as an x-axis for a graph plot which I forgot to mention before. Is there a way to implement this result into a graph?

Comment: @SajinGurung if you want to use it as an x-axis why are you writing it to a file? This seems like a completely unrelated question.